# Committee of 8 members out of 21 ( 12 men, 9 women)

Tags: combinatorics

A group consists of 12 men and 9 women. In how many ways can a committee of 8 members, 5 men and 3 women be formed.

Here's my logic : $C(12,5) \cdot C(9,3) = 792 * 84 = 66~528$

But this is different than the answer given in the book ($41~580$). Any clues of what I'm doing wrong here? It looked quite straightforward to me but I can't find my way to the right answer...

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your calculation.

Comment: Note: their answer is correct if you are only choosing $4$ men and $3$ women (or $8$ men and $3$ women).

Comment: This is odd, there is another exercice on the same book with : form a committee with 4 men and 4 women out of a group of 6 men and 5 women. My answer ($C(6,4) \cdot C(5,4) = 15 \cdot 5 = 75$) also differs from the solutions manual ($C(6,4) \cdot C(5,3) = 15 \cdot 10 = 150$) ...

Comment: I begin to suspect some very poor proof reading.  What book is this?

Comment: [Statistics for business and financial economics, page 201](https://tinyurl.com/y8cfa7jq) and [Study guide for the same book, page 62](https://books.google.ca/books?id=C3e1BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=%22A+senate+committee+consists+of+12+Democrats+and+9+Republicans%22&source=bl&ots=UV-FiO8pDW&sig=ACfU3U3nvrNUaIuF3ziPSaLpT_EyMrdOsA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwip6ffro4LgAhVTqoMKHeeCA90Q6AEwAHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22A%20senate%20committee%20consists%20of%2012%20Democrats%20and%209%20Republicans%22&f=false).

Comment: Combinatorics is tough on proofreaders.  A false argument can look more or less identical to a correct one.  By the same token, errors of this sort are tough on people learning the subject.  If you are just getting started, it's natural to imagine that any discrepancy is probably your error and not the text's.  I like the [Art of Problem Solving books](https://artofproblemsolving.com/) and, in my experience, they did an excellent job of proof reading.  Good luck!

Comment: Good to know! this would not be the first error so far on this book...